# Bootstrap sidebar visible-xs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I have the following **HTML** (ASP)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" runat="server">
        <!-- Added -->
        <div class="logo-header">
            <img src="Images/logo-small.png" />
        </div>
        <!-- Added -->
      <ul class="nav hidden-xs" id="lg-menu">
        <li runat="server" id="Home"><a href="home.aspx"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="Customers"><a href="customers.aspx"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Customers</a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="Reports"><a href="reports.aspx"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Reports</a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="AdminPanel"><a href="adminpanel.aspx"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Admin Panel</a></li>
      </ul>            
        <!-- tiny only nav-->
        <ul class="nav visible-xs" id="xs-menu">
            <li runat="server" id="Li1"><a href="home.aspx"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> </a></li>
            <li runat="server" id="Li2"><a href="customers.aspx"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> </a></li>
            <li runat="server" id="Li3"><a href="reports.aspx"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> </a></li>
            <li runat="server" id="Li4"><a href="adminpanel.aspx"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /sidebar -->
    <!-- main right col -->
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-11" id="main">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->        
</div>
```

and this **CSS**:

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {   
   padding-top: 50px;
}
#sidebar {
    padding:0px;
    padding-top:15px;
}
#sidebar, #sidebar a {
    color: #951013;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#sidebar .nav li>a:hover {
    color: #951013;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#sidebar .active > a,
#sidebar .active > a:hover,
#sidebar .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #951013; 
}
/* adjust the contents on smaller devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 968px) {
  .visible-xs{display:block!important;}
  .hidden-xs{display:none!important;}   
}
```

As you see i want to increase/override the **default max-width** to 968px but when i do that and visible-xs (**tiny nav**) gets visible its **width does not change**. It still needs to be 767 and then there remain only the glyph icons without the **space to the right**. How do i make the visible-xs the same as default but on 968px? **Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions in my answer:

1) A different code base that avoids using columns so the sidebar isn't reduced as the viewport changes; you can change the width of the sidebar with media queries then and have more control plus the sidebar is fixed so as you scroll through the main content of the page the sidebar is always there. The links have the same idea as far as hiding the text when you're at 968px.

2) Using your existing code, instead of having two separate menus you can use a class to hide the navigation text when you're at 968px.

**Solution #1 (New Codebase)**

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidebar-fixed {
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: none;
}
ul.sidebar-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li > a {
  color: #951013;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li > a:hover,
ul.sidebar-list > li > a:focus {
  color: #450C0E;
}
.main-content {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
@media (max-width: 968px) {
  .sidebar-fixed {
    width: 85px;
  }
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 85px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul.sidebar-list {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .sidebar-fixed li .nav-text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="http://placehold.it/50x20/f00">
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar-fixed" id="sideNavParent" runat="server">
    <div class="logo-header">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f00/fff?text=Logo" />
    </div>
    <ul class="sidebar-list">
      <li runat="server" id="Home">
        <a href="home.aspx"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i><span class="nav-text"> Home</span> 
        </a>

      </li>
      <li runat="server">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i><span class="nav-text"> Customers</span> 
        </a>

      </li>
      <li runat="server">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i><span class="nav-text"> Reports </span> 
        </a>

      </li>
      <li runat="server">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i><span class="nav-text"> Admin Panel </span> 
        </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
      <div class="alert alert-danger">Bootstrap Sidebar Navigation</div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
        unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
        the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
        typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
        Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution #2 (Original Codebase)**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#sidebar {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#sidebar,
#sidebar a {
  color: #951013;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#sidebar .nav li>a:hover {
  color: #951013;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#sidebar .active > a,
#sidebar .active > a:hover,
#sidebar .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #951013;
}
@media (max-width: 968px) {
  #lg-menu .hidden-item {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="http://placehold.it/50x20">
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" runat="server">
      <!-- Added -->
      <div class="logo-header">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      </div>
      <!-- Added -->
      <ul class="nav" id="lg-menu">
        <li runat="server" id="Home"><a href="home.aspx"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i><span class="hidden-item"> Home</span></a>

        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="Customers"><a href="customers.aspx"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i><span class="hidden-item"> Customers</span></a>

        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="Reports"><a href="reports.aspx"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i><span class="hidden-item"> Reports</span></a>

        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="AdminPanel"><a href="adminpanel.aspx"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i><span class="hidden-item"> Admin Panel</span></a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /sidebar -->
    <!-- main right col -->
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-11" id="main">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
      <div class="well">Well Well</div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
        unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
        the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
        typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
        Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Your first solution works fine but i would rather avoid the fixed width 150px if it's possible. Unfortunately your second suggestions works just the same as mine meaning the text is gone but the width remains the same.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the question then. What "width" are your referring to exactly?

Comment: I am referring the .sidebar-fixed width which is 150 and then become 85. I am using grid layout and i want to e.g. make it 3 columns width and when the size is < 968 to make it just one column or something like that.

Comment: I can't see anyway but these two options if you need to change the breakpoints of the actual columns to use 968px: You'd have to create a custom build [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) or use a pre-processor like [LESS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less) or [SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). Your sidebar and content would (most likely) still run into each once the viewport is reduced though.

Comment: It's OK I fixed it in a way that sidebar has the following classes: col-sm-1 col-xs-1 and the right column (main) has classes: col-sm-11 col-xs-11 well not ideal but works for me when i access the page from a tablet. Thank you for your help. It's much appreciated